# Convert in-memory (Map) representation of JSON to POJO (possibly with Jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a typical in-memory representation of JSON (A tree of nested maps, lists, and strings) and would like to convert them to a POJO.

For example, say I have a `Map<String, String>` representing the following structure.

```
{   
    "name": "Brennan",
    "profession:" "Software Developer",
    "hometown": "Phoenix"
}
```

I would like to convert it to an object of the following class.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String profession;
    private String hometown;

    /* Getters and setters */
}
```

One option would be to serialize the map to JSON using Jackson, and then deserialize it, again with JSON, to an object of type `Person`. Is there a less cumbersome way, that skips this intermediate step?

Comment: Write a constructor `Person(Map<String, Object>)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have a direct support for that by using `convertValue` method of jackson

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
 Person person = mapper.convertValue(map, Person.class);
```

note that this a logic equivalent to writing/reading from file, in a sense that the same conversion, serialization and de-serialization rules would apply. Its just faster as it is in-memory only